# Eclipse eRCP command framework - Unable to update command label dynamically

Tags: eclipse, command, label

I've scoured the web for the entire day trying to find an example on how to implement what I read concerning changing a command label dynamically here:

http:// wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI_Command_Design#Issue_102_-_Comm ands_implementation_of_label_changing

I have the a command defined in my plugin.xml that uses the suggested schema:

```
<command
     description="Hoping to change my state"
     id="my.commandWithState"
     name="Command Wtih State">
  <state
        class="org.eclipse.jface.menus.TextState"
        id="NAME"/>
</command>
```

In my handler, I have tried a lot of variations (including calling "getValue" before trying to set it in hopes of forcing a load to be called), but basically the gist is:

```
public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent pEvent) throws ExecutionException {
        pEvent.getCommand().getState("my.commandWithState").setValue("UPDATED!");
        return null;
    }
```

The state value itself is updated, but not persisted. I specified a style of "push" in the menuContribution area of my plugin.xml and the text on the command is always "Command With State" since I did not specify a label (though i expected it to change...)

I'm using Eclipse 3.6 so I assume I have the updates that supposedly allow this from 3.3.

The only way I have been able to set the text on the command ui object is to have my handler implement IElementUpdater like I'm working with a ToggleState. This allows me to change the text a total of 1 time, when I first start the product.

I'm about to tear my hair out.

1) The command "label" is not updated and 
2) the state value is not persisted even though TextState extends PersistedState.

What d>_